# Multiple Comparisons Adjustment for Sample Size in R

Tags: r, tukey, sample-size

I'm trying to compute a sample size for a study that has 5 groups. Aside from computing Cohen's *f* for the overall ANOVA, how can I compute a sample size for each group that adjusts for pairwise post-hoc comparisons, a la Tukey?  Is there a function in R that does this or would calculating Cohen's *d* and adjusting the alpha work here?

Comment: `TukeyHSD` is a built-in for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a power analysis. Take a look at [this blog.](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html) Specifically, you might use the `pwr.anova.test` function in R.